# Return two distinct data sets in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a bit of trouble trying to put a query together, any advice you have would be great :)

I look after a couple of test rigs that run a test approx every two minutes, logging the start of test date in sql. We're looking into cycle time, and I have a simple query that gives me all the tests between a certain time period, which I then throw into an excel table that gives me a pretty chart (for the managers) showing average cycle times for that week.

Current code looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PDATE,PlantNumber FROM [productline].[dbo].[Headertable]
Where PDate between '30DEC2021 00:00:00' and '05jan2022 23:59:59'
--and PlantNumber = 'test rig a' 
--and PlantNumber = 'test rig b'  
ORDER BY PDate desc
```

Which just returns a list of test dates for that time period. At the moment, I have to run the query twice to get a list of tests for each rig, commenting out the one I don't want to see. I'm trying to build a query that'll let me get both sets of test results in one query, but I'm not having much luck. The closest I have got is below:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @StartDate =    '30dec2021 00:00:00'
SET @EndDate =      '05jan2022 23:59:59'

SELECT 

(case when PlantNumber = 'test rig a' and PDate between @StartDate and @EndDate THEN Pdate else 0 end) as 'test rig a PDates',
(case when PlantNumber = 'test rig b' and PDate between @StartDate and @EndDate THEN Pdate else 0 end) as 'test rig b PDates'

From [Server].[productline].[dbo].[Headertable]
```

But this just outputs an unending list of dates, with 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 in every cell.

Any thoughts on what I can do to get this down to one query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help, see how to produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: .. and PlantNumber in ( 'test rig a', 'test rig b')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just needs an `IN`

And in Sql Server it's best to avoid using Oracle date literals.
Use `YYYY-MM-DD` instead.

```
SELECT t.PDATE, t.PlantNumber
FROM [productline].[dbo].[Headertable] t
WHERE t.PDATE >= '2021-12-30 00:00:00' 
  AND t.PDATE <  '2022-01-06 00:00:00'
  AND t.PlantNumber IN ('test rig a', 'test rig b') 
ORDER BY t.PDATE DESC, t.PlantNumber ASC
```

Comment: Honestly, if you're going to correct the formatting and conversion issue, why don't you both explain that and also fix the inclusive upper boundary issue (23:59:59)?

Comment: Hi LukStorms, thanks for your suggestion! I gave this a go, but instead of a list of individual PDates, I just got a PDate and a PlantNumber for each day within the specified range. I need a list of individual test dates as a result, so that we can calculate cycle time by looking at the difference between sequential PDates.

Comment: So I guess no rounding of the datetime then